# HTTP OPTIONS 405

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, http

I'm working with WebApi (MVC4) and I'm trying to communicate with it using JavaScript.
I have an action that is called with a POST request and there is a problem to get a custom header (*SpecialUser* for example) and I get an error in the OPTIONS HTTP method.

Without the header it works fine.

I've added the header to the Access-Control-Allow-Header in the config , but it doesn't fix it.

This is how the httpProtocol part in the config looks like :

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, SpecialUser" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Does anyone know what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you at least *describe* the problem? Is there an error? Does the `SpecialUser` header just not come down? Try to be more specific.

Comment: Add this : `Access-Control-Expose-Headers : SpecialUser`

Comment: There is an HTTP error status code (405) before the action really running. I've tried to add the header to the expose, but i'm still get the error